# Differential-difference equations for Poisson arrivals

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, queueing-theory, birth-death-process

A service station has one gasoline pump. Cars wanting gas arrive according to a Poisson process at a mean rate of 20/hour. However, if the pump is in use, these potential customers may balk (refuse to join the queue). To be more precise, if there are n cars already at the service station, the probability that an arriving potential customer will balk is n/4 for n = 1, 2, 3, 4. The time required to serve a car has an exponential distribution with a mean service time of 3 minutes.

1. For all k, find the differential-difference equations for $p_k(t) = $ Pr{k in system at time t}.
2. Determine the stationary probability distribution and hence find the average number of cars at the station.

---

I found a few similar exercises online, but with different things to compute. Nevertheless, I think this is a M/M/1 queue so that the equations are given by the formulas:

$\frac {dp_n(t)}{dt}=-(\lambda+\mu)p_n(t)+\lambda p_{n-1}(t)+\mu p_{n+1}(t)$ if n>0;

and

$\frac {dp_0(t)}{dt}=-\lambda p_0(t) + \mu p_1(t) $ if n=0

My first problem is I don't know what *k* is. Is it equal $0, ..., n-1$? If yes, then do I need to compute $p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3$ ? This would give

$\frac {dp_0(t)}{dt}=-20p_0(t)+20p_1(t)$

$\frac {dp_1(t)}{dt}=-35p_1(t)+20p_0(t)+20p_2(t)$

$\cdots $

Comment: There seems to be missing info in your question, did you really give all the info in your exercise sheet ?

Comment: This is an exercise 11.7.2 from the book "Probability, Markov Chains, Queues, and Simulation" which can be found on Google. There is no other information, only additional task ("Construct the transition rate diagram for this system") which I already solved so I did not include it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote $p_k(t)$ the probability that there is $k$ customers as pump $k$
And $\lambda^{in}_k = \lambda^{in}_0 (1 - k/4)$ the incoming rate of consumers at pump $k$ and $\lambda^{out}$ that rate at which customers finish their service.

After having written the diagrams for the system, you can deduce the following equation for the $p_k(t)$

- $\dot{p_0}(t) = - \lambda_0^{in} p_0(t) + \lambda^{out} p_1(t)$
- $\dot{p_1}(t) = - \lambda_1^{in} p_1(t) + \lambda^{out} (p_2(t) - p_1(t)) + \lambda_0^{in} p_0(t)$
- $\dot{p_2}(t) = - \lambda_2^{in} p_2(t) + \lambda^{out} (p_3(t) - p_2(t)) + \lambda_1^{in} p_1(t)$
- $\dot{p_3}(t) = - \lambda_3^{in} p_3(t) + \lambda^{out} (p_4(t) - p_3(t)) +  \lambda_2^{in} p_2(t)$
- $\dot{p_4}(t) = - \lambda_4^{out} p_4(t) +  \lambda_3^{in} p_3(t)$

Since $\lambda^{in}_0 = 20$ and $\lambda^{out} = 60/3 = 20$ and since for stationary probabilities, by definition $\dot{p}_k(t) =0 \ \  \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ you should be able to answer your question. This is the principle, I strongly encourage you to double check my calculations though.